# Dynamically changing selectInput choices with updateSelectInput within insertUI

Tags: r, shiny

We are developing a Shiny app allowing users to successively add `selectInput` widgets with country lists to the Shiny UI. However, the app should prevent users from choosing the same country twice by limiting the country list in each `selectInput` widget to non-chosen countries. Doing this in one direction, basically moving 'forward', works fine, but we want to extend this functionality to all `selectInput` widgets so that users cannot go back and make a duplicate choice in a previous line. So basically, we want to constantly update each `selectInput` option list by removing the already picked countries: moving forward while adding new widgets, retroactively for already existing widgets, and across all option lists if the user changes the country in a previous widget.

To exemplify, we have a vector of country names that is used as potential choices in a `selectInput` widget:

`country_list_1 <- c( "Argentina", "Belize", "Costa Rica", "Mali", "Peru", "South Africa" )`

The user chooses 'Argentina' in the first `selectInput` widget and then adds another `selectInput` widget via `insertUI`. Now Argentina is no longer an option for the new `selectInput` widget.

`country_list_2 <- c( "Belize", "Costa Rica", "Mali", "Peru", "South Africa" )`

The user now chooses 'Belize'; now Belize will disappear from the options of the first `selectInput` widget, whilst Argentina is still removed from the second option list.

`country_list_1 <- c( "Argentina", "Costa Rica", "Mali", "Peru", "South Africa" )`

If the user adds a third `selectInput` widget, Argentina and Belize will no longer appear.

`country_list_3 <- c( "Costa Rica", "Mali", "Peru", "South Africa" )`

But if the user returns to the first input widget and changes Argentina to Peru, all existing option lists should be updated accordingly.

`country_list_1 <- c( "Argentina", "Costa Rica", "Mali", "Peru", "South Africa" )`

`country_list_2 <- c( "Argentina", "Belize", "Costa Rica", "Mali", "South Africa" )`

`country_list_3 <- c( "Argentina", "Costa Rica", "Mali", "South Africa" )`

We tried to use `updateSelectInput` to update the options of each `selectInput` widget, but it seems not to work well with `insertUI`.

This is a simplified example of what we currently use:

```
library(shiny)

country_list <- list(
  "Africa" = c("Ghana", "Burundi", "Ethiopia"),
  "Europe" = c("Germany", "Belgium", "Luxembourg") 
)

# the first argument to a ui function should always be id
countryrow_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)

  fluidRow(
    column(9,
           uiOutput(ns("ui_placeholder"))
    )
  )
  
  fluidRow(
    column( 8,
            selectInput(ns("country"), label="Choose country: ", 
            choices=c("", country_list), selected=NULL)
    )
  )
  
  
} 

# create the module server function
countryrow_server <- function(input, output, session, choices) {
  ns <- session$ns
  
  # Placeholder
  output$ui_placeholder <- renderUI({
    type <- req(input$country)
    ns("inner_element")
  })
  
  # Update input to exclude previously selected country value
  #observeEvent(req(nchar(countries_selected2())>1), {
  reactive({
    updateSelectInput(session, "select", c(map(country_list, ~.[!(. 
    %in% choices())])))
  })
  
  
  returnValue <- reactive({
    input$country
  })
  return(returnValue)
}
#
#   UI
#
ui <- fluidPage(  
  
  actionButton("addLine", "Add Line"),
  
  countryrow_ui("country_0"),
  
  div(id="placeholder"),
  
  verbatimTextOutput("out"),
  
  textOutput("country1Text")
)

#
#   Server
#
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  handler <- reactiveVal(list())
  countries_selected2 <- reactive({ "" })
  # Leave blank for now
  countries_selected <- reactive({
    
    ""
  })
  
  # update first input module to exclude countries
  country_0 <- callModule(countryrow_server, "country_0", reactive({countries_selected()}))#, selected=reactive({country_0()}))
  
  # When button is clicked insertUI is added and updated to exclude previously selected countries
  observeEvent(input$addLine, {
    
    # new country id each time the button is clicked
    country_id <- paste("country", input$addLine, sep = "_")
    country_id_previous <- paste("country", input$addLine-1, sep = "_")
    print(country_id_previous)
    
    # insert new row for country selection using module ui function
    insertUI(
      selector = "#placeholder",
      where = "beforeBegin",
      ui = countryrow_ui(country_id)
    )
    
    # Extract country names and exclude these in country rows by running server function which updates country row server
    # Add country from new row to handler list
    handler_list <- isolate(handler())
    # call server function
    new_handler <- callModule(countryrow_server, country_id_previous, countries_selected2())
    handler_list <- c(handler_list, new_handler)
    names(handler_list)[length(handler_list)] <- country_id_previous
    handler(handler_list)
    
    
    test <- lapply(handler(), function(handle) {
      handle()
    })

    countries_selected2 <- reactive({
      as.vector(unlist(test))
    })
    
    output$country1Text <- renderText({
      
      new_id <- paste("row", input$addLine, sep = "_")
      paste("Country selection is", countries_selected2())
    })
  })
  
  output$out <- renderPrint({
    as.vector(unlist(lapply(handler(), function(handle) {
      handle()
    })))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Any ideas on how to solve this challenge are very welcome.

Comment: Please provide us with a [reproducible example](https://mastering-shiny.org/action-workflow.html#getting-help).

Comment: Out of pure curiosity: Why is this done across multiple selectInputs? A single `selectInput(multiple = TRUE)` should behave as intended.

Comment: Good point. The final app adds more widgets to each selected country; selecting the country is only the first step.

Comment: Still you could create several widgets for the selected countries of a single `selectInput`, right?

Comment: I could, but then I would run into the same problem with these widgets. Basically, what we do right now is that we create an entire row of widgets for the user to fill in by using insertUI. But the issue is that insertUI does not allow for retroactive modifications of the widgets. I will try to add a boiled-down code example of what we currently use.

Comment: Yes, an example would be helpful. In my eyes using update* functions is the right way to go (or `renderUI` if really needed).